# Want to replace some cells in workbook. Does Excel support regular expression in search and replacement?

Tags: regex, r, excel

I do not use Excel often, and have no idea about VBA. After I imported the data from excel to R(using `read.csv()`), all the missing data were replaced by *NA* . The *NA* remained there after I exported the data matrix through `write.csv()`. Now I want to clear all the cells with *NA*, and have tried to use regular expression as I did everywhere else. For example, I tried this in the search and replacement: `^NA$`, but it seems do not make any sense in excel. And I searched through google, while everyone are suggesting using VBA, which I know nothing about. I am wondering whether excel support regular expression in its search and replacement function. If does, then it would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: `write.csv` has an `na` argument. Did you try `na=""`?

Comment: You don't need regex for this. In the Find and Replace dialog box, search for "NA" (no quotes), leave the "replace with" box blank, and tick "match entire cell contents".

Comment: The above comments are relevant, but the short answer is: no, Excel does not support regex. If you are on Windows, you can [get a plugin that will add support](http://nielsbosma.se/projects/seotools/). Also, look at [this page](http://searchengineland.com/advanced-filters-excels-amazing-alternative-to-regex-143680) which discusses Microsoft's poor cousin of regex.

Comment: @sebastian-c That works fine! Thanks for telling me such an easy method!

Comment: @HongOoi That does not work, since I have some variables whose name contain the string "NA"(e.g., I have an variable called _FIRM NAMES_). All in all, thanks for you help!

Comment: @zenotsang That's why I specified to tick "match entire cell contents". This will exclude cells that contain NA as part of a string.

Comment: @zenotsang I'll write it up as an answer, then.

Comment: @nograpes Thanks, the plugin looks great and I will try on it later!

Comment: @HongOoi Really sorry for missing that important option. Have tried it just now and it also worked fine. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: As a side note: If you are passing your data regularly forth and back to Excel you might be interested in the R package `XLConnect` for reading and writing `xlsx` files directly.

Comment: @Beasterfield Thanks for reminding me. Actually I tried another function `write.xlsx()` in the package `xlsx`. I am not sure whether it differs largely from `XLConnect`. I found the `write.xlsx()` function is much slower than using `write.csv()` and then saving the generated file as `.xlsx` file.

Comment: @zenotsang I used to work with the `xlsx` package but moved to `XLConnect`for various reasons. Besides a bug which wasn't fixed for a long time, the clearer and simpler interface, which is also mightier is convincing.

Comment: @Beasterfield Thanks for your comments! I will try `XLConnect` later, and hope it works better than `xlsx`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `write.csv` function has an `na` argument. This determines what goes into cells with NA. By default, `na="NA"`. If you change this to `na=""`, you can have blank cells in your workbook.

For example:

```
write.csv(data, "data.csv", na="")
```